# Cyclic group and its order

Tags: group-theory

If $G=\langle x \rangle$ is a cyclic group of order $n$ and $m|n$. Show that $x^k$ has order $m$ if and only if $k =
 \frac{n}{m}k'$ for some $k' ∈ \mathbb Z$ with $gcd(k', m) = 1$. Conclude that $G$ contains precisely $φ(m)$ elements of order $m$.

Since $G$ has order $n$ then $x^n =1$.
First suppose $k = \frac{n}{m}k'$ for some $k' ∈ \mathbb Z$ with $gcd(k', m) = 1$. Then $(x^k)^m = x^{(\frac{n}{m}k')^m}=x^{nk'}$. But $x^n =1$ so $x^{nk'}=1$ and therefore the order of $x^k$ is $m$

For the other direction suppose $x^k$ has order $m$, then $(x^k)^m = x^{km} = 1$. But we know $x^n =1$. So $mk=nk'$ for some $k' ∈ \mathbb Z$ and therefore $k =\frac{n}{m}k'$

Is this proof correct? Also how do we conclude $G$ contains precisely $φ(m)$ elements of order $m$?

Comment: $\phi(m)$ is exactly the number of possible, nontrivial choices of $k'$...